# OpenSSL SSL_read: error:8006F074:lib(128):capi_rsa_priv_enc:function not supported

Tags: openssl, tls

Server Env : Ubuntu 22..04
Openssl 3.0.2
Apache 2.4.52
SSL x509 certificate is installed on the Apache Server

Client Env: Windows 2016
Curl 7.78.0
openssl 1.1.1f

Below command has been executed to sign a file via web api running on Server over https
curl.exe --request POST --cacert "ca.crt" --cert "user.crt" --engine capi --key-type ENG --key "user.key" --verbose -L "https://webapi:port" --header "content-type: multipart/form-data" --form "file=@file.txt" --output "out_file.txt"

tailed output
...
..
[5 bytes data]

- TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Hello request (0):
  { [4 bytes data]
- TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
  } [232 bytes data]
- TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
  { [117 bytes data]
- TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
  { [1319 bytes data]
- TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
  { [556 bytes data]
- TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
  { [1979 bytes data]
- TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
  { [4 bytes data]
- TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
  } [4292 bytes data]
- TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
  } [37 bytes data]
- TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, internal error (592):
  } [2 bytes data]
- OpenSSL SSL_read: error:8006F074:lib(128):capi_rsa_priv_enc:function not supported, errno 0
  0 82.4M    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
- Closing connection 0
  curl: (56) OpenSSL SSL_read: error:8006F074:lib(128):capi_rsa_priv_enc:function not supported, errno 0

I tried to disable tlsv1.2 and tlsv1.3 on server ssl.conf but still issue remains the same.